# Jenkins Windows Batch Command Powershell Environment Variables

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a PowerShell script to be executed as a build step in jenkins and need to pass environment variable to it

```
powershell -File .\Build.ps1 -Version $env:APP_VERSION_NUMBER
```

The `APP_VERSION_NUMBER` is an environment variable set by Version Number Plugin of Jenkins.

For some reason the `-Version` parameter is never set, and I see only `$env:APP_VERSION_NUMBER` in console log output.

Is this a syntax issue?

Comment: Is the variable APP_VERSION_NUMBER set in the machine or user context?  If you open a new powershell prompt and enter ${env:APP_VERSION_NUMBER}, does it give the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the PowerShell CLI's **`-File` parameter**, the **arguments passed to the script are treated as *literals***, so, given that you're invoking the command line *not from PowerShell*, `$env:APP_VERSION_NUMBER` is *not* expanded.

**To force the *target* PowerShell process to evaluate the arguments, you must use `-Command`** rather than `-File`:

```
powershell -Command .\Build.ps1 -Version $env:APP_VERSION_NUMBER
```

However, **now that we know that you're invoking the command line *via `cmd.exe`*** (a batch file) from Jenkins (a build step of type `Execute Windows batch command`), the simpler answer is indeed to **let `cmd.exe` expand the environment-variable reference, using its `%<envVarName>%` syntax**:

```
powershell -File .\Build.ps1 -Version "%APP_VERSION_NUMBER%"
```

<sup>Note: Enclosing the environment-variable reference in `"..."` isn't strictly necessary with a version number, but is a good habit to form, so that values with embedded spaces or other shell metacharacters are passed correctly too.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It turns out indeed its a syntax issue. The fix looks like the following

```
powershell -File ".\Build.ps1" -Version %APP_VERSION_NUMBER%
```

[image]